# When creating a new TFS workitem is it possible to configure a different default Iteration value?

Tags: workitem, tfs-workitem

Like many people we utilise the tree structure of each TFS project's **Iteration** field to organise the work items within that project. Typically we use it to track what iteration we are working in, so most of the time everyone creating a work item needs to put the same Iteration path value in new work items.

By default when you create a new work item (bug for example) this field is set to the root value of the defined tree. Given we have a tree structure in this field its fair to say that for 99% of WIs the default is never correct.

Is there a way to configure a TFS project to default the **Iteration** field to a specific value when creating a new work item?

Ideally this should be a *per user setting*, but a TFS project wide would still be better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to set a default value for Iteration or Area Path (at least not inside the WITD).

Two ideas come into my mind:

1. Create a custom control for your work items, install it on every PC and let it change the Iteration when the WI gets loaded.
2. Easier way: Get the power tools and create a template for your work items. There you can preselect the Iteration. Of course every user has to create their own template.

Comment: Ahh, snap! just discovered your option 2 myself. I think so far its the winner.

Answer (score 0):

[Andrei's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728795/andrei) answer lead me to some further internet research and I have found a option that fulfills my "this should be a *per user setting*" side of the equation;

- Instal the TFS Power tools extension.
- Define a new work item template
  (again following my example for a bug WI) and change the iteration
  path in the template to match that users current iteration path.
- Save
  the template.

From that point on you can add a work item using this template (team -> work item templates) and get the Iteration path default from the template.

Comment: Sadly this being personal requires each user to do this rather than having me (as TFS Admin) do it for them which is not ideal, but as a fix it should fly for our group.